# Print dictionary key inside 2 dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, printing

I am trying to make an app and I need a dictionary for that, but when I tried to access my stored values inside the dictionary I got an error message.

```
let dictt = ["Holmsbu":["water": true, "power": true],
             "Kragerø":["water": false, "power": true]]

print(dictt["Holmsbu"]!)
```

I tried to access it with this code:

```
print(dictt["Holmsbu"["water"]])
```

But all I got was this error:

> exit status 1
>   main.swift:2:22: error: cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'
>   print(dictt["Holmsbu"["water"]]!)
>                        ^
>
> main.swift:2:22: note: overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (String.Index), (Range), (ClosedRange), (Int), (Range), (ClosedRange), (CountableRange), (CountableClosedRange)
>   print(dictt["Holmsbu"["water"]]!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a `]` in the wrong place. It should be:

```
print(dictt["Holmsbu"]!["water"]!)
```

Even better is:

```
print(dictt["Holmsbu"]?["water"] ?? false)
```

I added the `?? false` to deal with all of the optionals. It's better than using `!` and having is crash if the keys are not in the dictionary.